# Jekyll displays in navigation bar links to index page

Tags: jekyll

What I'm doing wrong in jekyll that I have a link to Index page in the navigation bar?

```
>bundle exec jekyll --version
jekyll 3.3.1

>bundle --version
Bundler version 1.13.6

>ruby --version
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x64-mingw32]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it appears if `README.md` has the following content

```
# raisercostin's blog
```

It seems that it dissapears if `README.md` has the following content

```
# raisercostin's blog
My blog
```

It looks like a bug in the default and other themes.